# What type of visa code to use for Visa on Arrival

Tags: visas, applications, bangladesh

I am applying for NVR for Bangladesh. One of the fields for the online NVR prompts for last visa number which in my case was a Visa On Arrival at HSIA in Dhaka. Looking at the different code, I am not sure which to chose.
Please help.

Comment: What are the options? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

According to this guide https://bhclondon.org.uk/assets/theme/file/Guideline-to-fill-the-online-NVR-Appllication-Form.pdf the ‘last visa’ information applies only if you have previously visited Bangladesh with No Visa Required (NVR). If you have, put Yes and NVR related information. If not, then skip this part. Click save & next and go to next section.